# Probability of tossing regular coins 4 times in a row

Tags: probability

Presume we have 3 coins out of which two are regular and the third one has both tails. If we toss a random coin 4 times ( a coin is returned to the group after every toss ), calculate the probability that all tossed coins were regular if all 4 tosses yielded tails as result. My attempt was using Bayes theorem and obtaining the result of approximately 21 percent. Is this approach correct and if not, what is the correct way.

Comment: $(1/3\cdot1/2 + 1/3\cdot1/2 + 1/3\cdot1)^4$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A conditional probability calculation seems appropriate. However, $21\%$ is far from the truth. Let $A$ be the event "all tails" and $B$ the event "all regular." We want $\Pr(B|A)$, which is $\Pr(A\cap B)/\Pr(A)$.

The probability we get tail on a single toss is $\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}$. (We conditioned on the kind of coin tossed.) So $\Pr(A)=(2/3)^4$.

The probability of $A\cap B$ is also easy to calculate. The probability of regular **and** tail on a single toss is $(2/3)(1/2)$, so $\Pr(A\cap B)=(1/3)^4$. Divide. We get $1/16$.

Answer (score 0):

In a single toss there are four possible tails, all of them equally probable, and two of them are regular. So when we see a tail, the probability that it came from a  regular coin amounts to ${1\over2}$.

Therefore the probability that four tails seen in a series of experiments were all regular is $\left({1\over2}\right)^4={1\over16}$.